# Various forms of looping and iteration in Elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I am trying to understand all the looping constructs in Emacs Lisp.
In one example I am trying to iterate over a list of symbols and print them to the `*message*` buffer like so:

```lisp
(let* ((plist package-activated-list) ;; list of loaded packages
       (sorted-plist (sort plist 'string<)))
  (--map (message (format "%s" it)) sorted-plist))
```

`--map` is a function from the package `dash.el`.

### How to do this in pure Elisp?

Now how do I iterate over a list in Elisp, without using other packages.

I have seen some examples using `while` and `dolist` macro, for example here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html

But those are destructive, non-functional ways to express a loop.

Coming from `Scheme` (having worked with it and with SICP some twenty years ago!), I tend to prefer functional, non destructive (does that always lead to recursive?) ways to express ideas.

So what are idiomatic ways to loop over a list of items in Emacs Lisp?

Also: Are there ways to express loops in a functional fashion in Emacs Lisp?

### What I have found so far

1. **Loop Macros** (from Common Lisp?) prefixed with "cl-*"

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html

2. **Iteration Clauses**

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Iteration-Clauses.html#Iteration-Clauses

3. **`Dash.el`**

https://github.com/magnars/dash.el

Magnar Sveen's excellent package marketed as "A modern list api for Emacs. No 'cl required."

What else is there? Any recommended reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dolist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html#Iteration) is not destructive, and that is probably the most idiomatic way in Emacs Lisp, or Common Lisp for that matter, to loop over a list when you just want to do something with each member in turn:

```
(setq *properties* '(prop1 prop2 prop3))

(dolist (p *properties*)
  (print p))
```

The [`seq-doseq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#Sequence-Functions) function does the same thing as `dolist`, but accepts a sequence argument (e.g., a list, vector, or string):

```
(seq-doseq (p *properties*)
  (print p))
```

If a more functional style is desired, the [`seq-do`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#Sequence-Functions) function applies a function to the elements of a sequence and returns the original sequence. This function is similar to the Scheme procedure [`for-each`](https://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_560), which is also used for its side effects.

```
(seq-do #'(lambda (p) (print p)) *properties*)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a bunch of native ~map~ functions that you can explore for iterating throught lists, with some subbtilities or sugar.

In this case, I choose `mapconcat', it is loaded from C code.

> (mapconcat #'message sorted-plist "\n")

Comment: You might add a reference to this URL (Elisp's mapping functions) to your answer: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#Mapping-Functions

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more traditional Lisp `map` functions, e-lisp has them:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#Mapping-Functions

In your code snippet, `mapc` is likely the one you want (throws the values away, just applies the function; `mapcar` is still there if you want the values):

```
(mapc #'(lambda (thing) (message (format "%s" thing))) sorted-plist)
```

Comment: Except that `(format "%s" it)` won't work here because `it` is works only in `dash.el`.

Comment: You're right. Should've checked my code more carefully before posting. Will edit.